# How to force a match of "mark" of iptables to send its traffic to a TPROXY proxy?

Tags: networking, proxy, iptables, udp, transparentproxy

I am trying to set up a transparent proxy that works with marked packets generated by a [auxiliary program](https://github.com/zhangyoufu/fwmark) that wraps a process and mark its traffic with a firewall mark.

What this setup does is to force all marked packets to go through transparent proxies.

Here is my set up:

```
ip link add dum0 type dummy
ip link set dum0 up
ip -4 addr add 10.11.0.1/32 dev dum0
ip -4 route add blackhole default table 11 metric 9999
ip -4 route add default dev dum0 table 11 metric 95
ip -4 rule add fwmark 11 table 11
ip -4 rule add from 10.11.0.1 table 11
ip -4 rule add fwmark 10 table 10
ip -4 route add local 0.0.0.0/0 dev lo table 10
ip -6 rule add fwmark 11 table 11
ip -6 route add blackhole default table 11
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m comment -m mark --mark 11 -s 10.11.0.1 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 10000
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p udp -m comment -m mark --mark 11 --dport 53 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 10002
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p udp -s 10.11.0.1 -m mark --mark 11 -j TPROXY --tproxy-mark 10 --on-port 10001
```

TCP packets will be sent to a redirect proxy at 127.0.0.1:10000, DNS queries will be sent to DNS port 127.0.0.1:10000; UDP packets should be sent to a TPROXY proxy at 127.0.0.1:10001.

TCP and DNS are sent and received normally, but UDP packets stucks when trying to send over TPROXY. The table of TPROXY is apart from table of main firewall mark because if it was contained in the main firewall mark (11) it would drop the packets.

What am I missing with this set up? Is there something wrong with this configuration?

Answer (score 0):

I discovered what was wrong.

When TPROXY traffic in iptables comes from marked packets matched with "-m mark", the packets needs to be re-marked with the firewall mark of another routing table, that with local route pointing to loopback device (127.0.0.1).

Re-marking the packets is as easy as:

```
iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -p udp -m mark --mark 11 -j MARK --set-mark 10
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p udp -m mark --mark 10 -s 10.33.0.1 -j TPROXY --tproxy-mark 10 --on-port 10001
```

Packets with mark 11 will be re-marked to 10 and will be matched and processed by the the TPROXY iptables rule pointing to the table with local loopback route, and they will be sent to 127.0.0.1 accordingly.